# Match lead email to account website?

Tags: admin

Suppose john doe works for 'XYZ Company' and an account exists in Salesforce for XYZ. On the account level, the website is xyz.com and john's lead email address is john@xyz.com. Intuitively we should know this is a match because his domain in the email matches the website field for the account object.

Is it possible to set up a rule that would alert the lead viewer that a matching account was found for John Doe by finding an account where the domain of the email address is equal to the company website?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  I don't think theres any standard functionality for this.  One possibility would be to build a custom Lightning Web Component (with some Apex) to place on the record page and display a matched account if there is one.

Comment: There's an out of the box [Matching Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.matching_rules_standard_leads_on_accounts_rule.htm&type=5) that does exactly this. You will get an alert if you configure [Duplicate Mgmt](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management) to render a warning.